# $.getJSON fails on valid JSON?

Tags: php, jquery, json

I am pulling out my hair on JQuery/JSON issue where the response of `$.getJSON` function is not making sense.

So here is my Javascript code excerpt:

```
var jqxhr = $.getJSON("myPHPFunction.php", function() {
      alert("success");
    })
    .success(function() { alert("second success"); })
    .error(function() { alert("error"); })
    .complete(function() { alert("complete"); });
```

The JSON returned by the PHP function is this:

```
{"sid":"12", "name":"somename", "email":"someemail"}
```

Full response:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head><title>Untitled Document</title><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>
<body> {"sid":"12", "name":"somename", "email":"someemail"}
</body>
</html>
```

When I run the script, I get a dialog box saying `error`.

Several online validator have reported the JSON to be syntax-correct. Then why does JQuery fail? Note both the php and the script are in the same folder (on server) and same domain.

Comment: And what arguments do your error function receive ?

Comment: `console.log(arguments)` would be the easiest way.

Comment: what's the response code? and content-type?

Comment: The response is this: `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>

<body>
{"sid":"12", "name":"somename", "email":"someemail"}</body>
</html>`

Comment: There's your problem. you're returning HTML in addition to your JSON.

Comment: @dr_rk: Where is that HTML coming from?  You just need to echo the JSON, not all those tags.

Comment: Open `myPHPFunction.php` and remove all the html. Make sure the php code only prints json. View `myPHPFunction.php` in the browser, right click and view source. If you see anything other than json, you will continue to get the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your response must not contain any HTML!

Propberbly you also need to set the correct content type:

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
echo('{"sid":"12", "name":"somename", "email":"someemail"}');
exit();
```

The code above should work.

Please note that you must not output any other code before the header line.

Comment: Most of the time this isn't required.

Comment: The default content type is propberbly text/html I don't except that jQuery will accept this.

Comment: If the headers are sent as text/html, json doesn't really accept it. I personally wasted a few hours debugging this when I started with AJAX a few days back.

Comment: It will if you specify `dataType: "json"`, as he is doing by using `$.getJSON`

Comment: so on the php side HOW would I echo the header and the json?

Comment: @dr_rk try the code above. You just need to add `<?php` at the beginning.

Comment: @KevinB well you are right. Anyway the problem was the html output I made the part about the content type as a kind of extra.

Answer (score 3):

From the comments, you can't encapsulate the JSON in HTML markup. You'll need to ensure that the data returned ("View Source" is a good tool for verifying this) is pure JSON.